# AT-DP200 with Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt

I have heard of an issue with using the AT-DP400 DVI-MDP Adapter with a Thunderbolt display. I heard it will output a max resolution of 720p not the 2560x1440?

Has anyone tested this setup?

Comment: Is it 200, or 400?

Answer (score 1):

Found these on the manufacturer's web site:

> Note2: The DP400 requires Dual Link video card which support 2560x1440 in order to output 2560x1440 to a display. Please make sure you card is Dual Link.
>
> Note3: The AT-DP400 will not support 2011 iMac 27-inch with
>   Thunderbolt connection, Atlona is working on a new product which will.

Answer (score 0):

I have an AT-DP400, and it does not work with the Apple thunderbolt display. I tried various DVI dual link outputs from some PC, but the problem seems that the AT-DP400 is unable to power-on the thunderbolt display as a mac can do. A signal for powering-on the thunderbolt display is probably missing at the AT-DP400 mini displayport output...

At last november 2011, i asked if a new adaptor will be designed for this problem, they said that it will probably be available at end 2011. But i am still waiting.

I want to use my thunderbolt display with a PC and with my Mac book air. For my PC, i am still waiting for a solution, and for the moment i have connected an high resolution ZR2740W HP display.