# Connecting a Apple Thunderbolt Display 27 inch 2016 to a HP Elitebook 840 G8 via HDMI or USB-C or any active adapter?

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I tired using the HDMI to Mini Display Port Cable but it didn't work

In a different scenario I'm using Thunderbolt to USB C Adapter from Apple to get it working on my Apple Macbook Pro 2022 but I want to use for for my HP Machine and USB C Port on HP machine isn't working like Macbook Pro

Comment: You'll be able to connect the display, but the camera, mic, speakers and hub ports won't work.

Comment: Did I miss something here @benwiggy ? The Thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter [works bidirectionally on Mac and PC in my testing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/411399/5472). Seems the likely cause is no Thunderbolt on the PC

Comment: @bmike Exactly: if there's no thunderbolt, you can only use the display.

Comment: @benwiggy Mini-Displayport is not to be confused with Thunderbolt. The 2013 27in "LED Cinema Display" works over Mini-Displayport and connects the camera and speakers via USB. The 2016 "Thunderbolt Display" will only work over Thunderbolt.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI is not thunderbolt.
USB-C is not necessarily Thunderbolt.

[Apple Thunderbolt displays](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP642) are Thunderbolt only.

If the PC doesn’t have Thunderbolt, you will need to add that hardware for this to work. [DisplayPort can be embedded inside a Thunderbolt data connection, but Thunderbolt can not be embedded in HDMI or USB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411400/5472)

What makes this a little confusing: USB 4.0 hardware which is identical spec to Thunderbolt 3. So again, this comes down to, does your hardware have Thunderbolt or does it need an expansion/card added and [drivers for your chosen OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/169434/5472)?

---

Here are some links that have excellent details on this topic:

- [Connect a Thunderbolt Display to windows 8 desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181277/) (great tech details)
- [Are there adapters to use Thunderbolt Display with non-Thunderbolt computers?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17960/) (possibly the original “nope”)
- [AT-DP200 with Thunderbolt Display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36104/)
- [Surface Pro to Apple thunderbolt display 27](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269474/)